# How to integrate Firebase realtime database with FCM

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to integrate the Firebase real time database with the newly introduced Firebase Cloud Messaging services ?

I am building an app which uses the the Firebase realtime database for storing data. I want to notify my users using push notifications for every new insert in the database. I came across tutorials which teach you how to use FCM, but most of them require you to set up your own server for storing tokens. Is there a serverless way of integrating Firebase DB with FCM ?

I am new in firebase.. Please help

Comment: I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-firebase-cloud-messaging-on-android-d92cb4b53cfe) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseCloudMessaging). It's for Firestore, but the exact same logic can be used with the Realtime Database.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to send messages through Firebase Cloud Messaging is through an API that requires you to specify a so-called FCM **server** key. As its name implies, this key should only be used in trusted environments, such as your development machine, a server that you control, or a serverless solution like Cloud Functions/Cloud Run.

For an example of the latter, see the Firebase documentation on [notifying the user when something interesting happens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens). The basic approach explained there is as shown in this diagran:

[image]

So when some relevant data is written to the database (step 1), that triggers a Cloud Function (step 2), in which you then call the FCM API to send a message to the relevant user (step 3). It's not completely built-in, but based on the documentation and the sample code linked from there, you should be able to make a good start.